# Interrupts with Raspberry Pi and PiFace Digital

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have just set up a Raspberry Pi with the PiFace Digital element14 I/O board. So far, I've followed several steps to get it working such that I can interface with the I/O ports (control the LED's and operate the switches to do stuff) The python code I wrote works fine and I can make it do stuff.

Currently I'm just messing around, getting the feel for programming on the Pi, and trying to get an understanding for the features. I wanted to set-up a state machine for a simple 6-bit binary counter which counts up and down when I tell it to, which I was able to do pretty easily. But when I tried to take it to the next level and use interrupts for setting the state I ran into issues.

I followed the [Manual](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pifacedigitalio/latest/pifacedigitalio.pdf) as well as [This Guide](http://blog.oddbit.com/2013/08/05/interrupts-on-the-pi/) to get the code for activating the interrupts.

The code I wrote executes without error, however, either the interrupts are not detected or they don't do anything, I'm not sure which. My code is below. I know that the while loop works for the 'waiting' and 'counting' states because I can define the initial condition. It counts properly, so I feel pretty sure that the while loop is okay, there's just no state changes.

```
import pifacedigitalio as pfio
import os
import time

def startCounter(event):
 global state
 state = 'counting'
 print('counter started')

def stopCounter(event):
 global state
 state = 'waiting'

def stopProg(event):
 global state
 state = 'stop'

def resetCounter(event):
 global state
 state = 'reset'

def setLEDs(stateArray):
 i = 0
 for state in stateArray:
  pfio.digital_write(i,state)
  i = i + 1

def calcBools(count):
 binString = bin(count).rsplit('0b')[1]
 stringLength = len(binString)
 zeroString = '0' * (8 - stringLength)
 newString = zeroString + binString
 i = 0
 boolsOut = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 for bit in newString:
  if bit == '1':
   boolsOut[i] = 1
  i = i + 1
 return boolsOut

####################
### MAIN PROGRAM ###
####################

pfio.init()

pifacedigital = pfio.PiFaceDigital()
listener = pfio.InputEventListener(chip=pifacedigital)

signalDirection = pfio.IODIR_RISING_EDGE
listener.register(0, signalDirection, stopProg)
listener.register(1, signalDirection, startCounter)
listener.register(2, signalDirection, stopCounter)
listener.register(3, signalDirection, resetCounter)
listener.activate()

counter = 0
running = True
state = 'waiting'
setLEDs([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
direction = 'up'

while(running):
 if state == 'stop':
  running = False
  listener.deactivate()
  counter = 0
 elif state == 'waiting':
  time.sleep(1)
  print('waiting...')
 elif state == 'counting':
  if direction == 'up':
   counter = counter + 1
  else:
   counter = counter - 1
  if counter > 63:
   direction = 'down'
  elif counter == 0:
   direction = 'up'
 elif state == 'reset':
  counter = 0
 else:
  time.sleep(0.1)

 setLEDs(calcBools(counter))
 print(counter)
 time.sleep(0.25)
```

So this code doesnt work, and I tried something else which also didnt work using the pifacecommon library, replacing some of the lines of code with:

```
import pifacecommon as pfc

readport = pfc.mcp23s17.GPIOA    # I also tried GPIOB to no avail
listener = pfc.interrupts.PortEventListener(readport, 0)
```

After this the listener commands are identical for both methods. Along with this I attempted to use the pfc.mcp23s17.write command, but apparently it didn't exist or some foolish excuse like that.

Thanks in advance for reading this and even more if you respond, and more yet if you have an answer for me!

-Ben

Edit (SOLVED): My answer was in the comments of the 2nd link i provided the whole time :( Turns out I had everything written correctly, I just needed to run the file from the terminal and not IDLE3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my question was in the comments of the [2nd link](http://blog.oddbit.com/2013/08/05/interrupts-on-the-pi/) I provided the entire time. All I needed to do was run the program from the terminal, and not IDLE3.

I believe the reason lies in how interrupts are handled within Linux. Linux ISR's aren't true ISR's, the processor puts the ISR in a sleep mode until it's called. Can anyone elaborate on why IDLE3 doesn't support interrupts?